# In an Ionic 4 input form, how do I change the input color of date text?

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

Using a form in Ionic 4, I've got all my other inputs to show as white text, but cannot change the input text of the date field.  It keeps showing as black.  The placeholder is white as well.

```
<ion-item class="animated fadeInUp ion-no-padding">
  <ion-label position="floating">
    <ion-icon name="birthday" item-start></ion-icon>
    Birthday
  </ion-label>
  <ion-datetime color="secondary" formControlName="birthday" displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" 
    min="1940-01-01" 
    max="2020-01-01" ></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to try to add `class="color-white"` to:

```
<ion-datetime class="color-white" color="secondary" formControlName="birthday" displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" 
    min="1940-01-01" 
    max="2020-01-01" ></ion-datetime>
```

And add following to css:

```
.color-white {
  color: white;
}
```